# How to make RTK Query createApi's mutation throw rejection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

**How to make RTK Query createApi's mutation throw rejection?**

*The current code execution will enter then, How to get here.*

*getList({ id }).catch(() => { How to get here });*

> baseQuery.js

```
import { fetchBaseQuery, retry } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseQueryWithRetry = retry(
    fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    }),
    { maxRetries: 6 }
);

export const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    try {
        const result = await baseQueryWithRetry(args, api, extraOptions) as { data: { RES: string } };
        if (result.data.RES) {
            const { body } = JSON.parse(result.data.RES);
            switch (body.code) {
                case '000000':
                    return { ...result, data: body }
                default:
                    debugger
                    throw new Error('body.message');
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (err: any) {
        debugger
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}
```

> services.js

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { baseQueryWithReauth } from './baseQuery';

export const quoteApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'quoteApi',
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getList: builder.mutation<any, object>({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: 'getPriceList',
                method: 'POST',
                body,
            }),
        }),
    }),
    refetchOnReconnect: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so that your application is not littered with uncaught async exceptions if you are not interested in the result.

You can `unwrap` the result to get to "throwing" behaviour:

```js
getList({ id }).unwrap().catch(() => { How to get here });
```

That said, it is **very** likely that `getList` should be a query, not a mutation. Mutations are things that change data on your server.